# Formatting R combn output

Tags: r, combn

As a short example, when running `combn(1:5,2)`, I get a matrix of 2 rows and 10 columns. 
I know I can convert the output matrix to a data frame, but is it possible (any option inside `combn`) to have the output readily in the form of a **vertical** data frame of **2** columns and **10** rows ?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably simplest is `data.frame(t(combn(1:5,2)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply transpose the matrix with `t()`:

```
data.frame(t(combn(1:5, 2)))
```

Yields:

```
   X1 X2
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   1  5
5   2  3
6   2  4
7   2  5
8   3  4
9   3  5
10  4  5
```

Comment: OK, thanks ! I will do this, as it seems that no options is available in combn(*:*,*) to give directly a vertical dataframe output...